# How to bundle two iOS app into single ipa file

Tags: ios, swift, app-bundle

I have to bundle two iOS app into single .ipa File. So user can download two app with single download. I searched lot but can't find any docs to do this process. Also reviewed 'App Bundles' which is in iTunes connect that is only suitable for paid app. How to do 'App Bundles' with free apps? Can 'App Bundles' be supported to verify at the time of development?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - it's not possible to combine two apps in in one ipa file.

App bundles is just an iTC/AppStore term - you can bundle two or more iTC entities (apps) and sold them together at reduced price. And yes, bundles are only for paid apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine multiple app in single IPA. Because iTunes will recognize only one application in such IPA.